# How to align combobox popup to bottom Left wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

**Goal:** To align combobox popup to bottom Left. Kindly check image below for reference:

[image]

**What i tried?:** I tried playing with Placement property of PART_Popup. If i set Placement="Bottom", the Popup is rendering from Bottom right. Check this image below:

[image]

Also, in VS Designer it is showing correctly:

[image]

**ComboBox PART_Popup:**

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
       AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom"
       MinWidth="170">
    <themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"
                CornerRadius="3">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="False">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"
Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                    Margin="16"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
</Popup>
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
SelectedIndex="0"
Margin="50,0"
Style="{StaticResource FlatComboBoxStyle2}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Recent"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Alphabetical"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I am looking for XAML code solution only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a converter in App.xaml.cs:

```
    public class PositiveToNegativeConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (double) value > 0 ? 0 - (double) value : 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And define it in my ComboBoxTemplate:

```
<PositiveToNegativeConverter x:Key="PositiveToNegativeConverter" />
```

And call it like this in Popup's HorizontalOffest:

```
HorizontalOffset="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource PositiveToNegativeConverter}}"
```

I hope this helps out anyone looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and after following several thread here (all my XAML trial failed, to brief up, Popup.Placement = [whatever] didn't change anything on run) I ended up with the following "solution".

Not pretty, so if you knew more elegant way I'm open.

So I named my ComboBox and Add a event handler (via XAML) on DropDownOpen (this is the dirty side imo) where I force my Popup.Placement to RelativePoint and set a VerticalOffset to my ComboBox.ActualHeight.

Here is the XAML code :

```
<ComboBox Name="NIC_CmbBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DropDownOpened="NIC_CmbBox_DropDownOpened">
```

C# :

```
private Popup _comboBoxPopup;

private void NIC_CmbBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboPopupPlacement();
}

public Popup ComboBoxPopup {
    get
    {
        if(_comboBoxPopup == null)
        {
            //try to get it
            if(NIC_CmbBox != null)
                _comboBoxPopup = (Popup)NIC_CmbBox.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", NIC_CmbBox);
        }
        return _comboBoxPopup;
    }
    set => _comboBoxPopup = value; }

public void ComboPopupPlacement()
{            
    //If placement haven't already be done
    if (ComboBoxPopup != null && _comboBoxPopup.Placement != PlacementMode.RelativePoint)
    {
        _comboBoxPopup.Placement = PlacementMode.RelativePoint;
        _comboBoxPopup.VerticalOffset = NIC_CmbBox.ActualHeight;
    }
}
```